# Scikit Learn - Decision Tree - Visual Representation of the Outcome of Each Record

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a working decision tree and also a working .Dot output file from my training data. What I would like to do is output the decision tree process for each record. What I mean is that I would like to display to the user, rather as a tree with a single branch or even as text, what path each record followed to come to the decided outcome. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `decision_path` method ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.decision_path)) of the trained tree to see the path. However you may just need the `apply` method ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.apply)).  The `apply` method shows you the leaf node.  Since there is only one way to get to every leaf, knowing the leaf and seeing the tree the path is inferred.

How you want to display this is up to you and the user.  A table, a visualization, etc.

Comment: This is great. I want to display potentially two methods, once would be a visualization, the other would be a table. So for a table it would be Leaf|Value